# DriverManager.getConnection() throws exception for MySql DB access

Tags: mysql, gwt

I could not find a link to this issue.  I have searched for examples using MySQL and I am following the examples, but I still have this issue.  I am using GWT and I have set up a MySQL server on another host.  I want to get things working locally before deploying.  I am able to see the driver as the Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") call is successful.  The problem is getting the connection using DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password).  I know the credentials are correct.  The exception I am getting is:

java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.Socket is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

Based on other examples, I do not see what I am doing differently.  Could this possibly be because the SQL server is on a different host?  I have set the connection string using the IP address so I don't have to do a lookup:

private static final String url="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/dbname";

Yes, I have a valid IP where I have the XX's.  This code works fine if I am not running in the GWT.  Could this be because I am running the DB server on another host?  Is this not allowed?

Help is appreciated

Marty

Comment: Marty, are you doing the JDBC/Hibernate/whatever calls somewhere on the server side? Be sure that you do not try to call from clientside. Maybe you could share more settings like your query-code...

Comment: No, I am simply trying to connect to the database to do a query.  This should only require the Class.forName() call and a connect call.  Since I posted this, I am now using DriverManager.registerDriver(newAppEngineDriver());  With this call I can access the online SQL database, but still get the socket error with the local database.  You asked me to share the query code, I have not gotten there yet, I have to connect before I can do a query.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running on Google App Engine. You aren't allowed to use MySQL on GAE.

See [Can I use a MySQL database with an App Engine application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651629/can-i-use-a-mysql-database-with-an-app-engine-application)

Comment: Under settings for App Engine there is a section on Google Cloud SQL.  Under there you can choose to "Use MySQL instance" for development, which is what I am trying to do.  Are you saying that for development you cannot use a local database?

Comment: I believe you have to use Google's specific MySQL. Note the requirement to 'create a Google cloud sql instance' section: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/before_you_begin