# problems with psycopg2 on google apps engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, psycopg2, ponyorm

I get a problem when i tried to implement framework - Pony ORM in my google app engine application.
The point is that the Pony uses psycopg2 (PostgreSQL adapter), and when im trying to make a request to database it raises an exeption - that it cannot find the psycopg2 modul. (in local python enviroment - evrthg works correct)
Well, ive tried to manually add the psycopg package folder to the root of my project, but recieve the next error:

File "C:\Users\AcerFull\PycharmProjects\cloudepicerp\psycopg2__init__.py", line 50, in 
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 898, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named psycopg2._psycopg

_psycopg file have extension - ".pyd"  that means that it is not clear Python. As i understood, GAE works only with pure python
Im beginner in Python and Google AppEngine and actually i dont know how to fix this problem...

Comment: find a compatible ORM rather then trying to make something work that was built for a different DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** It seems that Google App Engine now supports PostgreSQL:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine

---

Google AppEngine does not support PostgreSQL. You cannot manage it to work.

The native GAE [datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) is not relational. Currently Pony ORM supports only relational databases, but in the future we can add support of NoSQL databases as well.

GAE allows you to use [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1651629/1706814) in form of [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction). We can add support of Google Cloud SQL in Pony ORM, but not right now, because currently we have more urgent tasks such as migration support. You can [open new issue](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/) if support of Google Cloud SQL is important to you.

Comment: Reading this just about made me cry lol. I am about to start a new project and plan to use app engine. I am a noSql guy so i wanted to do sql for experience. I have spent an hour getting super excited about pony orm. I read it works with mySQL and google cloud sql uses that so i thought i was golden. I just came across this randomly. I am a sql noob, what is the reason it won't work and instead a issue should be opened?

Comment: is this answer relevant today ?

Comment: @sherelock It seems that Google App Engine now supports PostgreSQL, I updated the answer