# Can Django, Google App Engine and Postgres work together?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, google-app-engine

I'm trying to transfer an Openshift-hosted Django website to Google App Engine. I wanted to connect it to an existing PostgreSQL database. However, I found this in [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/):

> A small percentage of native C python modules, and subsets of native C python modules are not available with Google App Engine. The disabled modules fall in to the following categories: (...)
>
> Please keep in mind that third party packages which use any of the above features will not function with Google App Engine (packages such as PostgreSQL, etc).

My local GAE server produced the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2._psycopg

[Further research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938809/problems-with-psycopg2-on-google-apps-engine) seems to indicate that this error was raised due to the limitations of GAE, rather than due to a configuration error. Surely there must be *some* reasonable way to connect my Django website with the externally hosted PostgreSQL server. What are my options?

**Edit**: so to clarify, I think I need a pure-Python replacement for `psycopg2` that works with Django. In other words, it should also implement a Django database backend I can use.

Comment: Have you looked into `gcloud`? https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/ It's an API used to interact with Datastore, which you can use to migrate things over from your Django application to an App Engine app. (i'm not sure if this applies to what you're trying to get done, but I figured I'd let you know anyways haha)

Comment: I want to keep my database hosted where it currently resides, so I need a way to let Django connect to my existing PostgreSQL database. The reason why I can't is because the standard PostgreSQL connector in Django (`psycopg2`) isn't pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [pg8000](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000).

Comment: This is only possible with a [Django database backend](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/xkHxgpE8Hsg). It looks like pg8000 doesn't have one, but the post I'm referring to was made in 2010 so I might be missing something.

Comment: They both implement Python DB API 2.0, so porting `django.db.backends.postgresql` from psycopg to pg8000 should be pretty straightforward - not much work besides find/replace.

Comment: Actually, `psycopg2` appears to implement some [non-standard features](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/lib/extensions.py) on top of DBAPI 2.0. It looks like porting that backend would also require `psycopg2`-specific logic like [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py#L50-L53) to have `pg8000` equivalents.